# Freshly installed gem (FactoryGirl) causes WEBrick to exit (DEPRECATION WARNING)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, factory-bot, webrick

trying to start WEBrick:

`rails s`

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
DEPRECATION WARNING: Change Factory.define to FactoryGirl.define
Exiting
/home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-2.6.1/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:6:in `define': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from /home/shawn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-2.6.1/lib/factory_girl/deprecated.rb:5:in `method_missing'
```

It's surprising to me because everything is freshly installed, and the same gemset works perfectly for others sharing the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ThoughtBot website http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/7176629856/factory-girls-new-look

Notice [this](https://github.com/corydeppen/rails3-mongoid-devise/commit/cc0268c4400e17c096d75db935e9732cab987a66) diff it looks like they ran into the same issue.

Somewhere you or someone is making a call to `Factory.define` when you should be calling `FactoryGirl.define`

`grep -ir 'Factory.define' *` from the application root directory should give you more details of exactly where you're making that mistake. If it doesn't return anything then you know it's not your app, it's some Gem (which is what the trace shows).

If that's the case I'd try `gem uninstall factory_girl` and `gem install factory_girl` to get a fresh version.

Comment: I indeed found three files where 'Factory.define' was used. But my team mates, with whom I share a repository, are not experiencing the same problem. Does that mean that they have an older version of the gem?

Comment: @Shawn yes my guess would be they haven't updated the Gem yet.

Comment: Ok, we solved the problem. We realized we weren't using exactly the same version of ruby (in addition to not having the same version of FactoryGirl).

Comment: I had the same issue. It turns out, that rvm used the factory girl version, which was previously build for ruby 1.9.3 for ruby 1.9.2 as well, resulting in the follwing bug: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/167 puring the system of all factory girl gems in all folders and bundling again solved my issues.